# How do I close a specified application on windows client workstations?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-access

I need close the catia applicaion at all client workstation during the license update process. At the time of the update, I need to prevent the use of the catia application.  I also need to close catia applcation before going to do license update .

Answer (score 5):

I would use pskill. This is included in the [System Internals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).

From here you can specify a list of computers and kill the process remotely. Then use psexec to restart it in a similar manner after the upgrade.

Comment: +1, seems like the best way that I know.